# Memory Leak in C and C++ Code

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to return a pointer from a function and use the return in a different function but I am getting memory leak.
The test code which I wrote and detected with memory leak by CPPCheck.

```
########################################################################

# include < stdio.h >
# include < malloc.h >
# include < string.h >

char* replace ( char* st, char* word, char *replaceWith );
int main ( void ) 
{
    char str[] = "Hello how are ## and what are ## doing ?";
    char word[]="##";
    char replaceWith[]="you";
    printf("%s",replace(str,word,replaceWith));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

char* replace(char* st,char* word,char *replaceWith)
{
 int i = 0;
 char *sr,*s,*ret;
 int oldlen;
 int count = 0;
 int newlen;
 int stlen;
 s=(char *)malloc(strlen(st) + 1);
 strcpy(s, st);
 oldlen=strlen(word);
 newlen=strlen(replaceWith);
 for (i = 0; s[i]! = '\0'; )
 {
     if( memcmp( &s[i], word, oldlen ) == 0)
     {
        count++;
        i+=oldlen;
     }

     else
     {
         i++;
     }
 }
 sr= (char *) malloc (i+1+count*(newlen-oldlen));
 ret = (char *) malloc (i+1+count*(newlen-oldlen));
 ret=sr;
 while(*s)
 {
     if(memcmp( s, word, oldlen) == 0)
     {
         memcpy(sr, replaceWith, newlen);
         s+ = oldlen;
         sr+ = newlen;
     }
     else
     {
         *sr++ = *s++;
     }
 }

 *sr = '\0';
 return ret;
}
```

Comment: You have to call free() function for every pointer allocated by malloc.

Comment: I have tried to call free. I can call free for sr and s as far as I understand but when I am calling the code crashes and as on "ret" I can not call the free from  the replace method I tried to attribute the responsibility to the calling context. Still it is crashing.

Comment: store return value of replace function in a variable and then call free from main function.

Comment: I am getting the message like : Windows has triggered a breakpoint in ReplacingTheString.exe. This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in ReplacingTheString.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded. This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while XXX.exe has focus. The output window may have more diagnostic information

Comment: Issue is with this line ret=sr; this will set ret to sr. Now sr and ret points to the same location and there is no way to access the memory allocated by this ret = (char *) malloc (i+1+count*(newlen-oldlen));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>

char* replace ( char* st, char* word, char *replaceWith );

int main ( void ) 

{

    char str[] = "Hello how are ## and what are ## doing ?";

    char word[]="##";

    char replaceWith[]="you";

    char * ret = replace(str,word,replaceWith);
    printf("%s",ret);
    free(ret); //freeing the allocated memory 
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

char* replace(char* st,char* word,char *replaceWith)
{

 int i = 0;

 char *sr,*s,*ret, *temps;

 int oldlen;

 int count = 0;

 int newlen;

 int stlen;

 s=(char *)malloc(strlen(st) + 1);
 temps = s; // storing the address of s in a temp location
 strcpy(s, st);

 oldlen=strlen(word);

 newlen=strlen(replaceWith);

 for (i = 0; s[i]!= '\0';)

 {

     if( memcmp( &s[i], word, oldlen ) == 0)
     {

        count++;

        i+=oldlen;

     }

     else
     {
         i++;
     }

 }
 sr= (char *) malloc (i+1+count*(newlen-oldlen));

 ret=sr;

 while(*s)
 {
     if(memcmp( s, word, oldlen) == 0)
     {
         memcpy(sr, replaceWith, newlen);

         s += oldlen;

         sr += newlen;

     }
     else
     {

         *sr++ = *s++;

     }
 }

 *sr = '\0';
 free(temps); // freeing the memory allocated for s
 return ret;

}
```

Comment: Thanks !!! Working without memory leak and crash. But I am not very clear that you copied the s in temps and freeing the temp only. So why not s and sr to be free .. Sorry, I am little weak in pointer and memory leak issues

Comment: while(*s){...} - this condition is true till s!= NULL. the condition is false when s== NULL . That is the reason I am storing s in a temp location.

Comment: Means you just freeing the address pointed by s by using free(temps). For the same reason can I think that sr can not be freed and must be freed in main function. That means the location pointed by sr will be freed by the call free(ret) in main .. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: yes. The location pointed by sr is freed in main function after printing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Always free same count with malloc.

1. free s, sr at end of replace,
2. use return value of replace instead of direct use on printf
   and free return value (return of ret from replace) when not needed.

Comment: While trying to do the same as suggested by you . I am getting the message like : Windows has triggered a breakpoint in ReplacingTheString.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in ReplacingTheString.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while XXX.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

Comment: while(*s)
 {
  if(memcmp(s,word,oldlen)==0)
  {
   memcpy(sr,replaceWith,newlen);
   s+=oldlen;
   sr+=newlen;
  }
  else
  {
   *sr++=*s++;
  }
 }
 *sr='\0';
 free(s);
 free(sr);

Answer (score 0):

I have doing lots of experimenting with the memory leak and meanwhile I wrote the following code. Please comment about the pros and cons side of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

// Prototype declaration of replaceAll function
static char* replaceAll(char *pSource, char *pWord, char*pWith);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//   NAME           :     main
//
//   DESCRIPTION    :     Implementation of main which invokes the replaceAll 
//                        function and displays the output             
//
//   PARAMETERS     :     void 
//
//   RETURNED VALUE :     int
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main( void )
{
    char *finalString = NULL;                           // To save the base returned address
    char srcString[] = "Hello how r you";               // Actual String 
    char pWord[] = "r";                                 // Word to be replaced
    char pWith[] = "are";                               // Word to be replaced with

    printf("\n Before Calling the replaceAll function:");

    printf("%s",srcString);

    printf("\n");

    finalString = replaceAll(srcString, pWord, pWith);  //calling the replaceAll function

    printf("\n After  Calling the replaceAll function:");

    // Checking if NULL is returned
    if( finalString != NULL )
    {
        //printing the string

        printf("%s", finalString);

    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Error: Blank String returned ");
    }

    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//   NAME           :     replaceAll
//
//   DESCRIPTION    :     Implementation of replaceAll function which replaces 
//                        a word in given string with another word         
//
//   PARAMETERS     :     char * 
//
//   RETURNED VALUE :     char *
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static char* replaceAll(char *pSource, char *pWord, char*pWith)
{

    char *pSt = NULL;               // Pointer to the source String to avoid modifying the pSource 
    char *pTarget = NULL;           // Target pointer to be malloced
    char *pTg = NULL;               // Pointer to the target string

    int count;                      // Counter
    int nWord = strlen (pWord);     // length of the word which needs to be replaced
    int nWith = strlen (pWith);     // length of the word with which the word needs to be replaced

    static const char nullP = '\0'; // null character 

    int szTarget = 0;

    // Assigning the base address of the pSource to a temporary and iterate through

    for ( pSt = pSource, count = 0; *pSt != nullP; pSt++ )
    {
        // Count number of occurances of the Word in the String to calculate the length of the final string
        if( memcmp( pSt, pWord, nWord ) == 0)
        {
            count++;
            pSt += nWord-1;
        }
    }

    // Calculate the required target Size
    szTarget = strlen (pSource) + count * (nWith - nWord) + sizeof (nullP);

    // Allocate memory for the target string

    pTarget = (char *)malloc(szTarget);

    // Check if the malloc function returns sucessfully

    if ( pTarget != NULL)
    {
        // Copying the string with replacement
        for (pTg = pTarget, pSt = pSource; *pSt != nullP; )
        {
            if( memcmp (pSt, pWord, nWord) == 0)
            {
                memcpy (pTg,pWith,nWith);
                pSt += nWord; 
                pTg += nWith;
            }
            else
            {
                *pTg++ = *pSt++;
            }
        }

        // Assigning NULL Character to the target string after copying
        *pTg = '\0';
    }
    return pTarget;
}
```